# file search across partitions in batch files

Tags: file, batch-file, location, partition

I am trying to create a batch file that will return a file location, including partition (or drive) so I can use it for more manipulation in that batch file.
The file name is known but the partition and directory are not known. Is that possible?

Comment: Edit your question and post some code that you have tried until now !

Comment: To search a certain file on a single drive, e. g. `C:`, you could use `where /R C:\ "filename.ext"`; to do that on multiple drives you could use a `for` loop, like `for %%D in (C: D: E: F:) do @where /R %%D\ "filename.ext"`...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
Title Searching for file by name 
Mode con cols=75 lines=3
cls & color 0A
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
If Exist %SearchResult% Del %SearchResult%
echo(
set /P "FileName=Type the file name for looking for = " 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" ^|find /i ":"') do (
    Set MyDrive=%%i
    echo( & cls
    echo(  & echo     Please Wait for moment .... Searching for "%FileName%" on "!MyDrive!\"
    @where /r !MyDrive!\ "%FileName%" >> %SearchResult%
)
Start %SearchResult%
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script -- let us call it `findfile.bat` -- searches for a file with the name given as a command line argument (for instance, `findfile.bat "lostfile.txt"`) on local disks and network drives as an example:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1" %%I in (
    'wmic LOGICALDISK WHERE ^( ^
        DriveType^=3 OR^
        DriveType^=4^
    ^) GET DeviceID'
) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        2> nul where /R %%J\ "%~1"
    )
)
```

The `wmic` command is used to retrieve the drives available on the current system. In the example there are two `DriveType` values allowed: `3`, meaning local disks, and `4`, meaning network drives. You can adapt the filter as you like -- reference site [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) for all the possible values. To not filter any drive types, simply remove the entire `WHERE` clause and use the remaining `wmic` command line `wmic LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID` instead.